# Riot.js example not working

Tags: riot.js

I was trying to test-drive Riot.js by using the example in the demo folder in Github but it is not working.
I checked everything and it seems OK.
Could it be a version issue?

Comment: I see what you mean: When you clone from git, and open `/demo/index.html`, there's an error. - However, the `/demo/pre-compiled.html` works fine. Is that sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: No, because I would like to test also browser compilation, so using todo.tag file instead of todo.js is important.

Comment: Well, I'll give it a try using pre-compiled js. Thanks Travis!

Comment: Examples were moved to the separated repo. FYI.
https://github.com/riot/examples

Comment: I also see inconsistency with the in-browser compiler: sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.